# MATLAB If statement with vector

Tags: matlab

I am very very new to MATLAB and have spent the majority of my day dancing around issues and I just couldn't Google my way out of this one.

My issue is that I am trying to use a vector in a nested if statement in such a way that I can evaluate a formula for a circuit. Doing some testing I found MATLAB will execute `if( t >=0 )` and `if( t <= 1e-2)` but will not work for `if( t <= 1e-3)`. This is an issue for me as my specifications require my `Period = 1e-3`, is there any way to get around this issue with my current instructions or do I have to completely redo my structure?

```
t = 0:1e-4:1e-2;
if (t >= 0 & t <= DutyCycle.*Period)
    ti = 0;
    tf = DutyCycle.*Period;
    Vci = 0;
 else
   if (t>= DutyCycle.*Period & t <= Period.*n)
        ti = t;
        tf = Period.*n;
        Vci = Vs;
      else
        if(t == Period)
            ti = t;
            tf = DC.*Period.*n;
            n = (n + 1);
            Vci = Vs;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: `t` is a vector. In your use case, are you expecting `ti`, `tf` and `Vci` to be vectors of the same size as `t` or scalars?

Comment: I think you've forgotten to include `for` before `t = 0:1e-4:1e-2`. In current code you're trying to compare a vector (`t`) with an scalar (`0`).